# AWS security group's Inbound rules for remote powershell execution?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, powershell-2.0

Which Inbound rules do I need to add for security group to execute powershell script from remote system in AWS. I need to run Invoke-Command to execute a command on remote system.
Do I need HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: Since this windows, you will be using WinRM service. The default HTTP port is 5985, and the default HTTPS port is 5986. Refer this link for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(v=vs.85).aspx